# Convert string to separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
str = "books:book1, books:book2, houses:house1, houses:house2, person:james";
```

I want to convert above string to separate arrays or arrays within an object, something like:

```
books = ["book1","book2"];
houses = ["house1","house2"];
person = ["james"];
```

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Is this in the browser?  The only way you'll be able to get true variables named for arbitrary strings is making the properties of the `window` object, which seems inadvisable.  Probably better to have an object that stores the properties.  Also, I'd be careful with a variable named `string`-- it's awfully close to the JavaScript `String`.

Comment: You probably want an object instead

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kywjx59u/

Comment: @anied, Thanks for the suggestion, I appreciate, variable name has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want an object, with keys containing the arrays.

```js
var str = "books:book1, books:book2, houses:house1, houses:house2, person:james";

var obj = str.split(',').reduce( (a,b) => {    // split the string on comma
    var parts = b.trim().split(':');           // split the parts on colon
    if (! (parts[0] in a) ) a[parts[0]] = [];  // if no key, create an array
    a[parts[0]].push(parts[1]);                // push the value to the array
    return a;                                  // return the object for next iteration
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = "books:book1, books:book2, houses:house1, houses:house2, person:james";
var hash = {};
var splitByComma = string.split(',');

function addKeyByVal( key, val ){
  if(!hash[key]) hash[key] = [];
  hash[key].push(val);
}

for( var s in splitByComma ){
  var splitByColon = splitByComma[s].split(":");
  addKeyByVal(splitByColon[0], splitByColon[1]);
}

console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on `', '` and reduce to an object containing `key: []`:

```js
const string = "books:book1, books:book2, houses:house1, houses:house2, person:james";
const output = string.split(', ').reduce((obj, cur) => {
   let [category, value] = cur.split(':');
   if (!Array.isArray(obj[category])) {
      obj[category] = [value];
   } else {
      obj[category].push(value);
   }
   return obj;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

`RegExp` method.

```js
var string = "books:book1, books:book2, houses:house1, houses:house2, person:james",
    arr = string.split(', '), obj = {}, res = [];
    
    arr.forEach(function(v){
      var array = [],
          elem1 = v.match(/\w+(?=:)/),
          elem2 = v.match(/(?:)\w+/g)[1];
      if (!obj[elem1]){
        obj[elem1] = [];
        obj[elem1].push(elem2);
      } else {
        obj[elem1].push(elem2);
      }
    });
    
    console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var string = "books:book1, books:book2, houses:house1, houses:house2, person:james";
var books = [];
var houses = [];
var person = [];
string.split(", ").forEach(function(e) {
    switch (e.split(":")[0]) {
        case "books":
            books.push(e.split(":")[1]);
            break;
        case "houses":
            houses.push(e.split(":")[1]);
            break;
        case "person":
            person.push(e.split(":")[1]);
            break;
    }
});
```

The code goes like this:

- Make three new arrays for `books`, `houses`, and `person`.
- Split the string into an array, separating by `,`.
- Go through each element in the new array and split it into *another* array, separating by `:`
- If the string on the **left** is `books`, `houses`, or `person` then append the string on the **right** to the `books`, `houses`, or `person` arrays, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This will put create global variables for you leveraging the `window`, but for the love of god please don't -- just use an object.  While this answer is what you *asked for*, the other answers are what you really *want*.

```js
var str = "books:book1, books:book2, houses:house1, houses:house2, person:james";
var splitStr = str.split(',');
var i;
var key;
var val;
var temp;

for (i=0; i<splitStr.length; i++) {
    temp = splitStr[i].split(':');
    key = temp[0].replace(/ /g,'');
    val = temp[1];
    if (!window[key]) {
        window[key] = [];
    }
    window[key].push(val);
}

console.log(books, houses, person);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the `split` string method twice to break down the data, then to make them into (almost) global variables, you can set them as window properties, however this can be dangerous if the values passed interfere with the existing properties.

```
var pairs = str.split(", ");
for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
  var key = pairs[i].split(":")[0];
  var val = pairs[i].split(":")[1];
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    window[key].push(val);
  }
  else {
    window[key] = [];
    window[key].push(val);
  }
}
```

This method is not recommended for cases where the source of the string is unknown, as it directly modifies window properties, some of which may cause unexpected behaviour if overwritten.